# Find sum of a column based on a value of a column(X) and get all values of another column where X existed

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery

I have the following table:

| id | code | amount | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 | 36 |
| 2 | 2 | 30 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 100 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 25 | 100 |
| 5 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 10 | 136 |
| 7 | 1 | 10 | 20 |

I want to find the sum of all amounts where code = 1, and for all such occurrences also want comma separated values of all qty and comma separated value of all ids.

Eg:
The output should look like:

| code | amount | quantities | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 36, 100,1, 20 | 1,4,5, 7 |

I know I can do something like

```
SELECT 
code
,SUM(amount) 
FROM 
table1 
where code = 1 
group by code;
```

for getting the sum corresponding to that code but don't know how to get all such quantities and ids.

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMvY7XqCxLNQ172hQ3CrqD/1)

Comment: `by` is not a function. Skips those extra parentheses and simply write `group by code;` - to make it clearer.

Comment: Check out group_concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `GROUP_CONCAT` to group all your data:

```
SELECT 
  t.`code`,
  SUM(amount) ,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.`qty` SEPARATOR ',') AS qtys,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.`id` SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM
  yourTable t 
WHERE t.`code` = 1 
GROUP BY t.`code` ;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` by default uses comma (,) as separator, so you can write same query as:

```
SELECT 
  t.`code`,
  SUM(amount) ,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.`qty`) AS qtys,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.`id`) AS ids
FROM
  yourTable t 
WHERE t.`code` = 1 
GROUP BY t.`code` ;
```

If you want some other separators, you can exclusively define that too.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL   you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

**Query #1**

```
select
        code,
        sum(amount)  as total_amount,
        GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids,
        GROUP_CONCAT(qty) qts

    from yourTable
    where code = 1
    GROUP BY code;
```

| code | total_amount | ids | qts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 1,4,5,7 | 36,100,1,20 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMvY7XqCxLNQ172hQ3CrqD/3)

In Postgres you can use `string_agg`

**Query #1**

```
select
        code,
        sum(amount)  as total_amount,
        string_agg(id::text,',') as ids,
        string_agg(qty::text , ',') qts

    from yourTable
    where code = 1
    GROUP BY code;
```

| code | total_amount | ids | qts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 1,4,5,7 | 36,100,1,20 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMvY7XqCxLNQ172hQ3CrqD/4)